# Pattern for unsaved changes

Tags: winforms, design-patterns

I'm developing a winforms app with lots of different forms and user controls.  Is there a recommended pattern that I could implement that notifies the user that there are unsaved changes on the current form/control when the form/control is exiting and also when the app is closing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using LLBL Gen pro for the ORM so that has some good entity tracking built into the objects.
I've kind of rolled my own that seems to work pretty well.
I created a new interface that my base User Controls and base Forms implement:

```
public interface IClosingNotification
{
    /// <summary>
    /// True if there is a dirty entity (or a dirty entity in the collection) present
    /// </summary>
    bool DirtyEntityPresent { get; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Register an entity to be watched for changes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity"></param>
    void RegisterForClosingNotification(IEntity entity);
    /// <summary>
    /// Register a collection to be watched for changes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="collection"></param>
    void RegisterForClosingNotification(IEntityCollection collection);
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the form should close without any notification
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    bool ShouldClose();
}
```

In my base control/form I have a collection of entities that I watch on each form, and I have a CloseForm() method in these classes that I use when a form is closing.
In my forms, whenever I create an object I can then register it for closing notification using:
RegisterForClosingNotification(MyCustomer);

It works well in our scenario.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Memento** is a way to encapsulate undoable changes.

   You can then keep a log of your uncommitted memento instances.

   But that's usually way to complex.
2. **State** is usually best.

   Your application has two "change" states:  Saved All Changes, Unsaved Changes.

   Each State has a transition rule based on "change" and "save" methods.

   - The Saved All Changes implementation of "save" does nothing.
   - The Unsaved Changes implementation of "save" sets the state to "Saved All Changes".
   - The Saved All Changes implementation  "change" sets the state to Unsaved Changes.
   - The Unsaved Changes implementation of "change" does nothing.